# Ways of thinking about vector-valued differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, vector-bundles, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to get a better intuition of vector-valued differential forms.

Let $V$ be a vector space and $M$ a smooth manifold. Consider the space $\Omega^k(M;V)=\Gamma((M\times V)\otimes \Lambda^k(T^*M))$. That is, the space of $V$ valued $k$-forms on $M$.

Intuitively I think of this definition as: For each $x\in M$, $\omega(x)$ is an alternating multi-linear map that maps $k$ tangent vectors at $x$ to a vector $v\in V$. In terms of the precise definition:

For $x\in M$, if $\omega\in \Omega^k(M;V)$, we have

$\omega(x)\in (\pi^{-1}(x))\otimes \{x\}\times\Lambda^k(T^*_xM)$

Firstly - is the above line correct? Since $\Lambda^k(T^*M)$ is a disjoint union, I would think that a section of $\Lambda^k(T^*M)$ would map an element $x$ of $M$ to $\{x\}\times T^*_xM$. So, because of the $\{x\}$ in the above equation, I feel like it is much more natural to think of $\omega(x)$ as the map described above but that it also outputs the point $x$ as well.

That is, $\omega(x)(X_1,\dots,X_k)=(x,v)$. Is this wrong?

What makes me a little uneasy is that since the bundle we are considering is trivial, does it not follow that $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is precisely $\{x\}\times V$? So then should it be

$\omega(x)\in (\{x\}\times V)\otimes (\{x\}\times \Lambda^k(T^*_x M))$...

Which just looks weird...

My understanding is not quite there yet. If anyone could help with this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

For ease of notation, let $(\mathbb{V}, \pi)$ be the trivial vector bundle $M \times V$; i.e., its total space is $M \times V$, and $\pi: M \times V \to M$ is projection onto the first factor. You are correct that $\pi^{-1}(x) = \{x\} \times V$, but this is canonically identifiable with $V$, so it's most natural to think of $\pi^{-1}(x)$ as simply $V$.

Let $\tilde{\pi}: \Lambda^k (T^\ast M) \to M$ be the projection. The fiber $\tilde{\pi}^{-1}(x)$ is usually denoted simply by $\Lambda^k (T_x^\ast M)$ (I think your $\{x \}$ is extraneous). By definition this is the vector space of alternating maps mapping $k$ tangent vectors in $T_x M$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

We are interested in the vector bundle $\mathbb{V} \otimes \Lambda^k (T^\ast M)$. Let's call it $(E, \pi_E)$, with $\pi_E: E \to M$. The tensor product means that the fiber over $x \in M$ is the vector space tensor product of the fibers of $\mathbb{V}$ and $\Lambda^k (T^\ast M)$:
\begin{align*}
 E_x :=& \pi_E^{-1}(x) \\
      :=& \pi^{-1}(x) \otimes \tilde{\pi}^{-1}(x) \\
      =& V \otimes \Lambda^k (T_x^\ast M)
\end{align*}
So for a section $\omega$ of $E$, $\omega(x) \in E_x = V \otimes \Lambda^k (T_x^\ast M)$. As you say, one way to think about this is as an alternating map mapping $k$ tangent vectors to a vector in $V$: $\omega(x)(X_1, \dots, X_k) \in V$. (Again, I think your $x$'s are extraneous.)

Here's a way to think of vector-valued differential forms that may feel more concrete. Fix a basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ for $V$. A vector $v$ in $V$ can then be specified by an $n$-tuple of real numbers $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ (where $v = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j$). Similarly, an element $\omega(x)$ of $E_x = V \otimes \Lambda^k (T_x^\ast M)$ can be specified by an $n$-tuple of $k$-forms $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$, where each $\alpha_j \in \Lambda^k (T_x^\ast M)$ and $\omega(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n v_j \otimes \alpha_j$. Since $\mathbb{V}$ is globally trivial, we can use the same basis for $V$ at every point, and think of a global section $\omega$ of $\mathbb{V}$ as an $n$-tuple of differential forms $(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n)$, where each $\omega_j \in \Gamma(\Lambda^k (T^\ast M))$ and at each point $x$, $\omega(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n v_j \otimes \omega_j(x)$. So a vector-valued differential form is really just specified by $n$ (ordinary) differential forms, once we fix a basis for $V$!

Comment: You beat me to the punch. Definitely +1.

Comment: Thanks for your response. $\pi^{-1}(x)=\{x\}\times V$ which can be canonically identified with just V, yes. I can see why this is convenient to do so. By definition, however, it strictly is the former. So does this mean 'strictly', without abusing notation to make things clearer and simpler, the output of $\omega(x)$ after acting on $k$ tangent vectors would be a point *and* a vector? Or is that statement false? Ie, no - it is not strictly a point and a vector, it is just a vector. (The reason I am 'hoping' it includes the point is due to an argument I'm working through elsewhere)